# MySQL Change varchar column to type set

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has data stored in a varchar column:

```
field varchar :company 
example data  : AB
                SD
                AB,SD
                SD,AB
```

The values are only supposed to be one of those combinations (the order does not matter). This column is probably better suited to be type *set* but it's *varchar*. I want to convert it to type set with the set's values being AB and SD.

I have a new column called companyFixed with possible values AB, SD.  How can I copy the values from the original column into the new proper column?

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET companyFixed = <this row's company values>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I haven't understood the question, but as far as I can tell this should work:

```
UPDATE myTable SET companyFixed = company;
```

I tried it myself, creating a table with a varchar field, then adding a SET field, and updating from one to the other. It worked.

Comment: You didn't miss anything that worked exactly as I needed! I didn't expect it to be so simple.